# Laravel: Render queried Data whith Blade functions

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Currently I'm getting some data from the database and after that I want to render it within my Blade template.
In my queried data I have blade functions like `url('/foo')` combined with some html. And here is the problem.

When I'm using `{!! $child->description !!}` the HTML is rendered correctly, but my Blade function won't work:

Function: `url('/foo)` 
Output: `http://myurl.de/url('/foo')`

When I'm using the "normal" Syntax like `{{ $child->description }}` the generated URL is correct (`http://myurl.de/foo`), but the HTML is not rendered.

So my question is:

How can I use my queried Blade function within rendered HTML? ^^

**/Edit**
Okay, perhaps my question is too abstract. So I want to show you my problem based on my example. ([generated template image - only on german, sorry](https://i.gyazo.com/f10701cc61e79c94568188d66e0378d0.png))

Every form is a database entry like:

- categoryName
- categoryParent
- ...
- categoryDescription

As you can see on my image, the categoryDescription is the small text under my first input field with the small button.
I want to use this script abstract as possible so that I can fill the entry with every content I want to fill in.
In this case my content is:

`lore ipsum <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" href="url('foo')">dolor</a>`

As you can see there is the mentioned Blade-function (url) and the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

{!! !!} - this dont escapse string so if u have something from database like, 
something it would output it like that.

While in other hand {{ }} this would give you just "something" without , it is used to protect you from injections.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. So I misunderstood the function all the time ^^ But my solution was correct so far, wasn't it? Do you have an idea how I can fix hat 'issue'?

Comment: I rly do not know why you are storing function in database insted of pure link?

Comment: So.. I've updated my question. I want to use the code multiple times on different webpages. So it would be fatal, to fix all my URLs manually instead of fix one constant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe blade error.**{{}}**

```
lore ipsum <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" href="{{url('foo')}}">dolor</a>
```

[Laravel Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade)